# Ubuntu 18 - HTTP2 enabled but serving http 1.1

Tags: server, apache2

I setup up http2 with [this guide here](https://techwombat.com/enable-http2-apache-ubuntu-16-04/).

I was originally getting the MPM Prefork error in my error log, so I followed [this guide here](https://http2.pro/doc/Apache).

According to this tool, http2 is enabled:
https://tools.keycdn.com/http2-test

But when I inspect in chrome I can still see that content is being served over http 1.1.

In my vhost file I have Protocols h2 http/1.1 right after the opening `<VirtualHost>` line

I tried the following command:

```
curl -I -k --http2 https://www.example.com
```

And the response was:

```
HTTP/2 200 
date: Fri, 20 Dec 2019 12:07:54 GMT
server: Apache
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-content-type-options: nosniff
referrer-policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
link: <https://www.example.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/", <https://www.example.com/>; rel=shortlink
cache-control: max-age=0, no-cache
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

I'm not sure what else could be wrong here, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Curl is responding with HTTP/2, as is the keycdn test. So your server is using HTTP/2 but your browser is not.

This suggests one of the following:

1. You are using anti-virus software which is intercepting the HTTP connection and downgrading it to HTTP/1.1. You can often turn off HTTPS scanning in your AV programs settings to avoid this.
2. You are using a [blacklisted cipher](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#appendix-A) that is not allowed to be used for HTTP/2. Some browsers (e.g. Chrome) enforce this and will use HTTP/1.1 if stronger ciphers are not configured in your server, though I think others (Firefox maybe?) don’t so you could check with that to see if that’s the issue. Or use the [SSL Labs tool](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) to see what ciphers will be used.
3. You’ve cached content or using a [service worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54513933/requests-served-from-serviceworker-are-downgraded-from-http-2-to-http-1-1) so Dev Tools is not reporting the protocol your site supports.